# How to distribute binary-only packages for different go versions

Tags: go

I am planning to distribute a binary-only package for different golang versions. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: note that binary only packages will no longer be supported in go version 1.13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this [distribute a binary-only package for different golang versions?

No.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i would like to know the alternatives on how a package is distributed to the enterprise customers. I understood that we didn't have any centralized go repository where we place the package code and distribute similar to pypi(python).

Comment: @SrimanNarayana You can ship the source code. Or you can host it somewhere, e.g. in your git repo and let your customer access your git if they provide the appropriate credentials (which is a git issue only, unrelated to Go).